# What are some popular Robotics APIs/Frameworks

Tags: api, frameworks, robotics

I am developing a robotics Library for Arduino, I would like to be able to stand on the shoulders of giants and ensure I am covering the major requirements. Is there any popular, well built, robotics API out there I could peruse to see typical robotics functionalities? The hardware platform is irrelevant.

Comment: Google `Arduino robotics library`. The search results are ranked by popularity. Your question is entirely too open ended for StackOverflow; it asks for opinion ("What's popular?") and isn't specific. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), which says in part "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." - read the rest of that paragraph as well. Voting to close as not constructive for that reason. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[ROS (Robot Operating System)](http://www.ros.org/) is the defacto standard.

You can find tutorials covering the platform on [their website](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

You'll also find a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup) on using ROS with the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

ROS is the open source standard.